# Sed replace asterisk symbols

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm am trying to replace a series of asterix symbols in a text file with a -999.9 using sed. However I can't figure out how to properly escape the wildcard symbol.

e.g.

```
$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/************/-999.9/g'
sed: 1: "s/************/-999.9/g": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

Doesn't work. And

```
$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/[************]/-999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9-999.9,-5.0
```

puts a -999.9 for every * which isn't what I intended either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/[*]\+/-999.9/g'
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/[*]\+/-999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,-999.9,-5.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Any of these (and more) is a regexp that will modify that line as you want:

```
$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/\*\**/999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0

$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/\*\+/999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0

$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed -r 's/\*+/999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0

$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/\*\{12\}/999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0

$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed -r 's/\*{12}/999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0

$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/\*\{1,\}/999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0

$ echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed -r 's/\*{1,}/999.9/g'
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0
```

sed operates on regular expressions, not strings, so you need to learn regular expression syntax if you're going to use sed and in particular the difference between BREs (which sed uses by default) and EREs (which some seds can be told to use instead) and PCREs (which sed never uses but some other tools and "regexp checkers" do). Only the first solution above is a BRE that will work on all seds on all platforms. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

`*` is a regex symbol that needs to be escaped.

You can even use BASH string replacement:

```
s="2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0"
echo "${s/\**,/-999.9,}"
2006.0,1.0,-999.9,-5.0
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\*\+/999.9/g' <<< "$s"
2006.0,1.0,999.9,-5.0
```

Comment: I'm surprised that first command doesn't introduce a ton of `-999.9`s since `\**` means **zero** or more occurences of `*`. The output of `echo "2006.0,1.0,************,-5.0" | sed 's/\**/999.9/g'` is `999.92999.90999.90999.96999.9.999.90999.9,999.91999.9.999.90999.9,999.9,999.9-999.95999.9.999.90999.9` I'd have expected you to need `\*\**` for **one** or more, like `\*+`, in shell just as you do in sed and other tools but clearly you don't and idk why!

Comment: Actually `\**` is not even a regex it is a glob pattern matching a literal `*` followed by anything and that's why I have `,` in the end to stop this.

Comment: Ah, globbing, of course. Just one more clue that the shell is not for text manipulation as even the stuff they use that LOOKS like it's for text manipulation is actually something completely different that makes sense for file name generation instead! Maybe change the first sentence from `* is a regex symbol` to `* is a wildcard symbol meaning repetition that's used in the shell for globbing and in UNIX tools like sed, grep, awk for regexps` and then state which is which in your 2 scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Ya, `*` are special meta character which repeats the previous token zero or more times. Escape `*` in-order to match literal `*` characters.

```
sed 's/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/-999.9/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

When this possibility was introduced into gawk I have no idea!

```
gawk -F, '{sub(/************/,"-999.9",$3)}1' OFS=, file
2006.0,1.0,-999.9,-5.0
```